# Find lat and long from address Json Pasing

Tags: android, json, google-maps-api-3

Web service :

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=pune+India&sensor=false

Following Json is i'm getting:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Pune",
               "short_name" : "Pune",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Pune",
               "short_name" : "Pune",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Maharashtra",
               "short_name" : "Maharashtra",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "India",
               "short_name" : "IN",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Pune, Maharashtra, India",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 18.62719520,
                  "lng" : 73.98963809999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 18.41367390,
                  "lng" : 73.75319080
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 18.52043030,
               "lng" : 73.85674370
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 18.60505030,
                  "lng" : 73.98480309999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 18.43576840,
                  "lng" : 73.72868430
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import com.pxr.tutorial.xmltest.R;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


        JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=pune+India&sensor=false");

        try{

            JSONArray  earthquakes = json.getJSONArray("location");

            for(int i=0;i<earthquakes.length();i++){                        
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
                JSONObject e = earthquakes.getJSONObject(i);

                //map.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));
                map.put("name", "Earthquake name:" + e.getString("lat"));
                map.put("magnitude", "Magnitude: " +  e.getString("lng"));
                mylist.add(map);            
            }       
        }catch(JSONException e)        {
             Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.main, 
                        new String[] { "name", "magnitude" }, 
                        new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        final ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                   
                Toast.makeText(Main.this, "ID '" + o.get("id") + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Can anybody please help me out to parse lat and long of the Json in android. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problem understand the JSON pattern of your response,

I hope I understand correctly and written this,

```
        JSONObject mainObj= new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray jArray = mainObj.optJSONArray("results");
        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject temp = jArray.optJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject loc = temp.optJSONObject("geomatery").optJSONObject("location");
            loc.getString("lat");
            loc.getString("lng");
        }
```

Comment: JSONObject mainObj= new JSONObject(response);      how we can get respoce ?

Comment: Man,you are already doing it in your code `JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=pune+India&sensor=false"); `

Comment: String respose = json.toString();   
  JSONArray mainObj = json.getJSONArray(respose);
  JSONArray jArray = mainObj.optJSONArray("results");

Comment: its giving error on mainObj.optJSONArray("results"); i have also tried by doing this JSONArray jArray = mainObj.getJSONArray("results");

Comment: The method getJSONArray(int) in the type JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=pune&sensor=false");
  String respose = json.toString();    
  try {
   JSONArray mainObj = json.getJSONArray(respose);
   JSONArray jArray = mainObj.getJSONArray("results"); 
   for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    JSONObject temp = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
     JSONObject loc = temp.optJSONObject("geomatery").optJSONObject("location"); 
     loc.getString("lat");
     loc.getString("lng");

Comment: Updated CODE:   JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=pune&sensor=false");
  String respose = json.toString();    
  try {
   JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject(respose); 
   JSONArray jArray = mainObj.optJSONArray("results"); 
   for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    JSONObject temp = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
     JSONObject loc = temp.optJSONObject("geomatery").optJSONObject("location"); 
     loc.getString("lat");
     loc.getString("lng");

Comment: Instead `mainObj` just use your `json` ..that's it no need to convert again to string and make object..

Comment: you mean to say.... this one..    JSONObject json  = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=pune&sensor=false");
JSONArray jArray = json.optJSONArray("results");